# Animating ListView Container when list has been populated

Tags: android, listview, android-animation, listadapter

I have a framelayout that contains a ListView that's used for search suggestions. In an activity's onCreate, I would like to animate this ListView container with drop-down style after the adapter for this ListView has been set and populated. By populated, I mean the pause state in which either the full list of suggestions have been populated and put on screen or the entire screen capacity has been reached.

I was wondering if there exists a way for me to know when this state has been reached(as opposed to animating one listView by one in my listAdapter's getView) just so I know when I can get the "true height" of the list in which I can then use to somehow animate the drop down animation.

Thanks for the help